# How can I get the step size from a RangeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

When I print a RangeIndex, I can see that it "knows" what it's step size is.

```
>>> r = pd.RangeIndex(0, 15, 3)
>>> print(r)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=3)
```

I'd like to access this as an attribute, but I don't see anything like "step" or "step_size" as an attribute (or even start and stop for that matter). Is this possible to do? I've tried following the source code but it's beyond me.

Comment: If you `r.__dict__`, you can see that `r._step` will solve your problem ;)

Comment: Ah thank you! This seems like an odd step to take, should I avoid doing it?

Comment: The `_` is an indicator that this attribute is not part of the object's public API and is subject to change without notice.

Comment: Thanks for the info – I wonder why they don't make it stable and accessible, like `freq` for `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: The reason is that a `RangeIndex` is not that 'stable' as a `DatetimeIndex`, i.e. a `RangeIndex` can easily become a `Int64Index` (which has no step) on an indexing operation.